# Strange character littering the buffer on the cursor line

Tags: cursor

When I edit a file in vim on my laptop running OL8 (a RedHat variant) inside a gnome terminal, there is a strange character on the left margin of the cursor line. The character is "sticky", making a column of litter along the left margin as I move the cursor around the file. It does not seem to make a difference what column the cursor is in, the litter always appears and sticks along the left margin.

[image: vim with strange character littering the buffer]

This does not occur over ssh with the same user account when editing the exact same file. Any suggestions?

Comment: It looks like the sequence `ESC [ = 0 C` which looks odd as an ANSI or VT100 or xterm sequence... What does `echo $TERM` in the shell (or `:set term` in vim) return to you? Maybe try `export TERM=xterm` or `export TERM=screen` on the shell before you run vim to see if that helps?

Comment: In vim it's `term=cons25` and in the shell it's `screen-256color`, and these values are identical on the local terminal (with garble) and over ssh (without garble). Changing `TERM` on the shell didn't make any difference in a subsequent vim session. The gnome shell profile specifies the usual character encoding `UTF-8`, and it doesn't look like any special emulation settings are active.

Comment: It's odd that you're getting `term=cons25`, not sure where that might be coming from... What does Vim tell you for the `:verbose set term?` command, to ask where it's defined? Does `:set term=screen` or `:set term=xterm` or similar fix the issue you're having?

Comment: That works! On all my machines I have `term=cons25` , but for some reason, setting `term=xterm` inside vim on this machine resolves it. So there'll be a wonky one-off in my vimrc... unless that's a normal setting for any environment?

Comment: The `term=cons25` setting is quite unusual, I haven't seen that before... The `:verbose` command was supposed to tell you where it's coming from. Did you try it? `:verbose set term?` is the command.

Comment: That was actually in my `.vimrc`, and I vaguely remember putting it there to resolve an issue with some kind of specific customization (following a blog recommendation). Obviously I should have put a comment on it, but anyway, if that issue still exists then I'll have to find a different workaround for this machine.